# Convert hexadecimal string to numeric IP Address in PHP

Tags: php, hex

i want to convert this kind of address **0xC0A8071B** to a numeric Ip Address (ex: 192.168.96.55)

How to do that in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use good old [`long2ip()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php) here:

```
echo long2ip(0xC0A8071B);
```

Output:

```
192.168.7.27
```

A nice feature is that the parameter can be passed as numeric or string representation, this can be seen here: http://3v4l.org/P8TRB

The function `ip2long()` can be used to convert into the other direction, from an IP to a number. However, both functions will work with IPv4 addresses only.