# How can I convert this string into a human readable IP address in PHP?

Tags: php

I've got a string representing an IPv4 address:

```
$ip = '\x7F\0\0\x01';
```

When I try to pass that to `inet_ntop($ip)` it's giving me grief:

> PHP Warning:  inet_ntop(): Invalid in_addr value

If I declare the variable manually using double quotes it works:

```
$ip = "\x7F\0\0\x01";
inet_ntop($ip); // "127.0.0.1"
```

However, I am not declaring these variables manually. I'm working with what is given to me in an object.

How can I convert `'\x7F\0\0\x01'` into a string that `inet_ntop()` will accept?

In other words, how can I make PHP parse a string literally as if I were manually declaring it with double quotes?

---

Some interesting facts:

```
gettype('\x7F\0\0\x01'); // string
gettype("\x7F\0\0\x01"); // string
ord('\x7F\0\0\x01'); // 92
ord("\x7F\0\0\x01"); // 127
implode(unpack('H*', '\x7F\0\0\x01')); // 5c7837465c305c305c783031
implode(unpack('H*', "\x7F\0\0\x01")); // 7f000001
mb_detect_encoding('\x7F\0\0\x01'); // ASCII
mb_detect_encoding("\x7F\0\0\x01"); // UTF-8
"\x7F\0\0\x01" == '\x7F\0\0\x01'; // false
// and for the haters
long2ip('\x7F\0\0\x01'); // PHP Warning:  long2ip() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given
```

Comment: Put it in double quotes????

Comment: @Sherif How do I do that if the variable is provided to me?

Comment: How is the variable provided to you? You said it was a *literal*. i.e. you can *literally* change it.

Comment: @Sherif `$ip = "$ip";` does not work

Comment: I  meant put the **string literal** in double quotes. Not the variable. A variable is something already stored in memory. A string literal is the code you're writing in your IDE/texteditor.

Comment: Why would you write `$ip = '\x'` and then try to modify that value at runtime? Why not just write `$ip = "\x"` and the problem goes away.

Comment: @Sherif you are misunderstanding the question. OP receives the string literal `\x7F\0\0\x01` from something like an API. He is not writing that value himself otherwise he wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @Sherif - `SomeOther\Library\GivesMe::ip()`?

Comment: And where in that question does it state this string comes from an API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert hexadecimal string to numeric IP Address in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985403/convert-hexadecimal-string-to-numeric-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: @MartinZeitler `long2ip` expects its parameter to be an `int`, not a string.

Comment: @Sherif "I am not declaring these variables manually. I'm working with what is given to me in an object"

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to parse the string into its component pieces (starting with `\`); convert them to the decimal equivalent and use `chr` to get back the original characters. These can then be joined into a string which is suitable for `inet_ntop`:

```
$ip = '\x7F\0\0\x01';
preg_match_all('/\\\x?([\dA-F]+)/', $ip, $parts);
$ip = implode('', array_map(function ($v) { return chr(hexdec($v)); }, $parts[1]));
echo inet_ntop($ip);
```

Another alternative is to use [`pack`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php), after stripping out the `\x` parts and replacing `\0` with `00`:

```
$ip = '\x7F\0\0\x01';
$ip = pack('H*', str_replace(array('\x', '\0'), array('', '00'), $ip));
echo inet_ntop($ip);
```

In both cases the output is:

```
127.0.0.1
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VL1U3)

Comment: I appreciate it Nick and this is the direction that I am headed, but I'm really hoping to find something a little more straightforward and readable.

Comment: @BenHarold I've added a slightly simpler solution using `pack`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've got the literal ASCII output of a binary string and not the real binary value you expect it to be. I'm not sure how you got the literal ASCII value. There is a way to convert it, but you're not going to like it.

You can use `eval()` to accomplish what you're trying to do. *All arguments for `eval()` being evil still apply.*

```php
$ip = '\x7F\0\0\x01';
eval("\$ip = \"$ip\";");
echo inet_ntop($ip);
```

This will print out `127.0.0.1`.

Since binary doesn’t always result in literal ASCII characters, I worry you’ll see literal characters like � in the strings, and these won’t convert properly to the binary value you expect them to be.

For example, here are the characters printed to screen in [Psysh](https://psysh.org):

```php
>>> hex2bin('7f000001') // This is 127.0.0.1
=> "\x7F\0\0\x01"
>>> hex2bin('ffffffff') // This is 255.255.255.255
=> b"ÿÿÿÿ"
```

The first value looks familiar, right? That's the string literal that we can convert back into a binary string using `eval()`, like we did in the example above. But the binary value for `ffffffff` is a different story. If we try to convert it, it doesn't give us the `255.255.255.255` value we expect.

```php
$ip = 'ÿÿÿÿ';
eval("\$ip = \"$ip\";");
echo inet_ntop($ip);
```

In this case, `inet_ntop()` returns `false`, but we know it should work:

```php
>>> inet_ntop(hex2bin('ffffffff'));
=> "255.255.255.255"
```

So, I worry that any attempt to convert these values from string literals into binary strings is not going to work in all cases, whether using `eval()` or any of the other answers provided here.

However, if everything is coming to you in the format `\0\0\0\0`, where each "segment" is either a zero or a hex value in the format `x00`, then you should be in good shape, because these are the same:

```php
>>> "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"
=> b"ÿÿÿÿ"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own function like this

```php
function convertStringToInAddr(string $string) {
    $return = null;
    $exploded = explode("\\", $string);
    foreach($exploded as $hex) {
        if( $hex != "" ) {
            $return .= chr(hexdec(str_replace("x", "", $hex)));
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```